# codeception entity associations with Doctrine 2

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, codeception

I'm unit-testing my Symfony 2 application with Codeception.

For one test, I want to fetch the associated entity in a one-to-one relationship, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it, because codeception complains no matter how I do it.

My first try:

```
    $log_id = $I->grabFromRepository('BM2SiteBundle:Realm', 'log', array('id' => $realm_id));
```

error:

> 1) Failed to test the realm details in RealmBasicsCest::testRealmView
>   (/Volumes/User
>   Data/Users/Tom/Sites/BM2/src/BM2/SiteBundle/Tests/functional/RealmBasicsCest.php)
>   Sorry, I couldn't grab from repository
>   "BM2SiteBundle:Realm","log",{"id":1}:
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9
>   near 'log FROM BM2\SiteBundle\Entity\Realm': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

2nd try:

```
    $log_id = $I->grabFromRepository('BM2SiteBundle:EventLog', 'id', array('realm' => $realm_id));
```

error:

> 1) Failed to test the realm details in RealmBasicsCest::testRealmView
>   (/Volumes/User
>   Data/Users/Tom/Sites/BM2/src/BM2/SiteBundle/Tests/functional/RealmBasicsCest.php)
>   Sorry, I couldn't grab from repository
>   "BM2SiteBundle:EventLog","id",{"realm":1}:
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: A single-valued association path
>   expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an
>   explicit join instead.

definition of the one-to-one relationship:

`one-to-one field="log" target-entity="EventLog" inversed-by="realm" fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`

For further testing I need the id of the log to construct a URL.